# How to draw time series line chart using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, time-series, linechart

I have big data set with two columns and I use spark with pyspark module to analysis the data set. I try to draw line chart using "date" column and "count" column. But date column included 4 years details but those are not in order(according to day by day), dates are mixed. So firstly I want to re arranges the dates, past to present. and this date column, data type is string. Can I know to draw this time series line chart, this date column should have to convert in to "date type" if it is how I change this string type date values in to date types values?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your question really about drawing a line or about converting a string to date? I understood you are asking about the latter.

Comment: mainly I want to draw line chart but befor draw a chart I want to convertdate axis in order

Comment: OK. So, given you have your dataset right, you still don't know how to draw a line chart. Is it correct?

Comment: I'm new to spark. I don't know to draw line chart using spark. but I suppose to draw line chart for this two variables converting data frame in to panda data frame then using matplotlib module.. but before the drawing I want to re arrange date column in to ordered dates.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Before drawing the chart, you need to convert the Spark DataFrame into some Python data structure. It could be a Pandas DF or "collecting" the Spark DataFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Spark 2.4.3, you can convert your string dates like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

df = sparksession.createDataFrame(
    [("8 October 2018", 4407), ("17 September 2017", 13326)],
    ["date", "count"],
)
df.show()

df.select(
    sf.to_date("date", "d MMMMM yyyy").alias("new_date"), "date", "count"
).orderBy("new_date").show()
```

And these are the results:

```
+-----------------+-----+
|             date|count|
+-----------------+-----+
|   8 October 2018| 4407|
|17 September 2017|13326|
+-----------------+-----+

+----------+-----------------+-----+
|  new_date|             date|count|
+----------+-----------------+-----+
|2017-09-17|17 September 2017|13326|
|2018-10-08|   8 October 2018| 4407|
+----------+-----------------+-----+
```

PS.: For **Spark 3.0.0**, the string format has changed. The date conversion should use the string `"d MMMM yyyy"` (one less `M`), as it is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

### Chart

To draw a line chart, you could use Pandas and matplotlib:

```
pdf = (
    df.select(
        sf.to_date("date", "d MMMMM yyyy").alias("new_date"),
        "date",
        "count",
    )
    .orderBy("new_date")
    .toPandas()
)

pdf.plot.line(x="new_date", y="count")
```

Comment: @bochat107 I followed your steps but my new_date columns not crated like your one. It creates null values. but that column, value type converted as date. I attached screen shot in question area below..

Comment: Hum... Which Spark version are you using?

Comment: version 3.0.0-preview2 this is the spark version

Comment: As I suspected, the date format seems to have changed for newer versions of Spark. Can you try `"d MMMM yyyy"` (one less `M`)?

Comment: 1) what is meaning of - **NameError: name 'sparksession' is not defined** how I resolve this issue?

Comment: @randunugalhena, `sparksession` was the variable I have defined for my Spark session. Your code probably uses another name, maybe `ss`. I can't tell the name from your printscreens.

Comment: So can I know how I define sparksession as ss? can you send complete method to define spark session?

Comment: How have you created your DataFrame? Could you show the code line used to read your dataset? From this code line, I could probably tell you the name of your variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211967/discussion-between-boechat107-and-randunu-galhena).

Comment: `df3 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("Reviews.csv")` This is the way I imported my csv file in to spark